# Django - Retrieve Values of Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, checkbox

How do I retrieve the values of multiple html checkboxes and send it back to my view? The checkboxes have the same name:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="document_1" name="checkbox_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="document_2" name="checkbox_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="document_3" name="checkbox_1">
```

I'm trying to give the user the option the select multiple checkboxes and then send that data back to a Django view.

My hope is to send the data back to a Django view as a list of all the selected values with Ajax, although I'm just working out a regular form right now.

So If I selected the first and last checkbox, I would send this back to the view:

```
data = ["document_1", "document_3]
```

I have tried setting a variable like this:

```
var data = $('.checkbox_1:checked').val()
```

and I'm still working on the Ajax but haven't been able to make much progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Test the boolean `checked` property for each checkbox (in either jQuery or in native javascript);
2. Build an array from the results;
3. Optionally convert the array into a conventional object (javascript arrays are already objects); and then
4. Convert either the conventional object or the array into JSON (which you can then send via Ajax).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var checkedCheckboxes = [];

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('input').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                checkedCheckboxes.push($(this).val())  
            }
        });

    // Now we have an array
    console.log('JS Array: ');
    console.log(checkedCheckboxes);

    // Convert array to standard Javascript Object Literal
    var checkedCheckboxesObject = $.extend({}, checkedCheckboxes);
    console.log('JS Object: ');
    console.log(checkedCheckboxesObject);

    // Convert Object Literal to JSON
    var checkedCheckboxesJSON = JSON.stringify(checkedCheckboxesObject);
    console.log('JSON: ');
    console.log(checkedCheckboxesJSON);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="document_1" name="checkbox_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="document_2" name="checkbox_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="document_3" name="checkbox_1">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround it with a form:

```
<form method="post" id="list-action">
<input type="checkbox" value="document_1" name="checkbox_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="document_2" name="checkbox_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="document_3" name="checkbox_1">
<button type="button" class="js-use-selected">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and then in your ajax, do this:

```
$(".js-use-selected").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/',
    data: $("#list-action").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data) {

    }
  });
});
```

In your `views.py` you can get a list of the "checkbox_1" values by the name of checkbox elements:

```
values = request.POST.getlist('checkbox_1')
```

if it doesn't work, try this:

```
values = request.POST.getlist('checkbox_1[]')
```

And then, for example:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(fieldname__in=values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="checkbox_1" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="checkbox_2" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="checkbox_3" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="checkbox_4" class="checkbox">
    <button type="button" id="submit-button">Send data to server</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected_items = [];
    $(".checkbox").click(function(){
        var selected_item = $(this).val();
        var index = selected_items.indexOf(selected_item);
        if(index == -1)
        {
           selected_items.push(selected_item);
        }
        else{
           selected_items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
    $("#submit-button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/',
            data: {'checkboxes': selected_items.join(","), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': {{csrfmiddlewaretoken}} },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

In django views, you can get the value of checkboxes using `request.POST['checkboxes']`. Applying `split(',')` method to this value will separate values of every checkbox.